# Synonymize [loot] -> [treasure]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I just noticed we have both a [loot](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loot) tag and a [treasure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure) tag. They both mean the same thing - providing or acquiring items - and [four questions are tagged with both](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loot+treasure).

Could we make [loot](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loot) a synonym of [treasure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure), thus keeping [treasure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure) as the main tag? I don't have any score in either tag, so I can't suggest the synonym the usual way.

Treasure's the more formal term, and apparently the more commonly used tag by a small margin. Plus it has a (very brief) tag wiki, and loot doesn't.

Comment: Do either have a tag wiki?

Comment: @Brian Treasure has a small one. Loot doesn't.